# Why are tires that fit 622mm wheels called 700C

Tags: tire, wheels

where does the 700 come from and what does the C stand for in 700c?

Comment: To be as confused as everyone else, see what Sheldon says about [Tire Sizing Systems](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html).

Comment: This /question/ is not a duplicate.  I searched.  I agree it has been /answered/ within the linked questions.

Comment: Yes, I searched too. But now your question links to that one :-)

Comment: user1816847 -- duplicate questions are not a problem, they are useful to users like @andy256 find questions. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/ for more info.

Comment: @AnotherUser Lol. Great link :-)

Comment: @andy256 I've seen it linked to in enough places around SE to know to Google `Dr Strangedupe` so I could link to it :)

Comment: @AnotherUser Jeff includes only a picture from Dr Strangelove, here's the [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snTaSJk0n_Y). Completely off topic of course!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/17273/how-do-i-determine-my-wheel-size) or [this link](http://centurycycles.com/tips/tech-talk-know-your-tire-size-pg1275.htm), the idea was originally that there were 700A,700B,700C tires+wheels which all had an outer diameter of 700 mm with A tires being the thinnest and C tires being the thickest (so A had the largest rim and C had the smallest rim). Eventually, the C variant won out, and people varied the outer diameter by mounting different tire sizes on a 700C rim.

Comment: So, it became really a big mess. If the americans and british adopted the ISO (the [I] in the acronym comes from International) things would much easier for everyone.