# Need help understanding wheel sizes

Tags: wheels, rims

Wheel Diameter: 64cm/25 inch what does this mean? I'm thinking of buying a new bike. but Ive never heard of 25 in wheels. Or is the 64cm a 700c. I've only had 26 in up till now and my knowledge in the cm is next to none. can anyone help me please?

Comment: Do you have a source for these numbers? These are not standard numbers, but 25 inches is equal to 635mm which just happens to be the other 28" rim size.

Comment: As with @ojs, I think you need to clarify where you’re getting these numbers from. Can you include a screen shot or photo of the source you found them at? Otherwise we might have to close this as “unclear what you’re asking.”

Comment: https://www.cndirect.com/product-detail-listing-2739499898.html?currency=USD&gclid=CjwKCAjw-NXPBRB4EiwAVNRLKkouoVSNUqQpiXwbmu-jcbga578RrezkC2mufsHiUKwNf9B41Vy20hoCkC0QAvD_BwE

Comment: sorry i dont know how to do a screen shot

Comment: Looks pretty shady. The seller doesn't know standard tire sizes and can't be bothered to check what's printed to the tire, the fork is mounted backwards in photos. I wouldn't order this unless I was explicitly looking for problems.

Comment: i watched the video and it looked like it worked good. so tire size is uncertain then?

Comment: It's uncertain. Why is it even important?

Comment: just tring to get a grasp of what they were tring to mean

Comment: Well, there are two options. Either they're honest and have no idea what they are selling, or they know that they are selling a piece of crap and the shady details are there to discourage anyone who knows anything about bikes from buying and then complaining later.

Comment: A 26x1.5" tyre is almost exactly 25" due to the oddities of tyre sizing systems. Using that measurement rather than the size stated on the tyre is a clear sign of a product marketed by and aimed at clueless people

Comment: Wheel size is a lot easier to understand if you understand that it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Check out @DanielRHicks [answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/31870/4239) on the duplicate. It should help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Having a look at the link provided in the comments the wheel make and model is pretty clear. Following a swift Google search the same wheel is advertised on Amazon as a 26".

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Hybrid-Front-Wheel-Knives-Dx3000/dp/6254401010

So, any 26" tyre  should fit you fine, although I'd be questionable of the seller, as mentioned in the comments above.